# Counting problem: ways of opening stores in non-adjacent blocks?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A coffee company wants to set up stores along the main street of town, which has $n$ blocks. The company won’t open two stores in the same block, or in two adjacent blocks.
Q: For this coffee shop, determining a way of opening stores is equivalent
to determining a set of blocks that have stores. Give a recurrence for the total number of ways that the company could open stores in town.

I have been stuck on it for awhile, please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Since the company opens at most one store in a block, if a town has $n$ blocks, we can represent any possible way of opening stores by a string of $n$ zeroes and ones: a $0$ represents a block in which the company does not open a store, and a $1$ represents a block in which the company does open a store. The other restriction means that we want only those strings that do not contain two adjacent ones.

Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of $n$ zeroes and ones that do not contain two adjacent ones. (Call these the *good* strings.) Suppose that we know $a_k$ for $k<n$.

- Every good string of length $n$ that ends in $0$ is obtained by appending a $0$ to a good string of length $n-1$, and every good string of length $n-1$ can be extended in this way to a good string of length $n$ ending in $0$, so there are $a_{n-1}$ good strings of length $n$ that end in $0$.
- Every good string of length $n$ that ends in $1$ must actually end in $01$ (assuming that $n\ge 2$), so it’s obtained by appending $01$ to a good string of length $n-2$. Conversely, you can start with any good string of length $n-2$ and append $01$ to get a good string of length $n$ ending in $1$. How many good strings of length $n$ ending in $1$ are there?

Put the pieces together to get your recurrence. You should also determine $a_0$ and $a_1$ (or $a_1$ and $a_2$, if you don’t want to consider towns with $0$ blocks of main street).

Answer (score 0):

Consider leftmost part: there must be either store, then gap, then something or gap then something. So $f(n)=f(n-2)+f(n-1)$.